# Docker image loading shows "no disk space error" in windows 10?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-image, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to load a 14GB image tar file in the docker. At some point, loading fails and throws a "no disk space error".

Folwing Steps were taken:

- Removed all the images and containers from docker.
- Modified the Docker Virtual hard disk size to 40GB using VBoxManage.

*I have seen some similar question in stack overflow but their environment and conditions were different.*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. My steps were right but needed to allocate more size. I modified the VDI to 60GB and it worked.